# Getting coordinates from a sequentially indexed array for LED display

Tags: python, arrays, c

My son asked me an interesting question involving a Art/Engineering project he is working on.  He is working on an array of LEDs made from a single strip of LEDs that will be controlled by an Arduino.  The LEDs on the strip are indexed sequentially and the grid is made by running the strip back and forth, so the index locations of the LEDs in the array look like (the actual grid is 17x17, but this is representative):

```
 1  2  3  4
 8  7  6  5
 9 10 11 12
16 15 14 13
```

He wants to use the arduino to create "squares" of LEDs, so needs to figure out how to select the correct LED indexes to create the shapes.  This was not obvious to him!

I have come up with a solution (I'm mocking it up in Python, though he'll eventually need C) that is math-based to convert index number to coordinates (and vice versa), which works fine:

```
# size of LED array is n x n
# find coordinates given index (x) of led
def findxy(x,n)   : 
    # figure out row
    row = (x-1)//n + 1
    
    # figure out column
    if row%2 == 1:
        col = x - n*(row-1) 
    else:
        col = n*(row) - x + 1 
        
    return row,col

# find index of led, given coordinates
def findx(row,column,n):
    x = (row-1)*n
    if row%2 == 0:
        x += n-column + 1
    else:
        x += column
    return x
```

It also occurred to me that I could simply create the array with the index values (as pictured above) and just use coordinates to find the index value at that coordinate.  To reverse that, I could search the array for a given index number to find the corresponding coordinates.  Which seems simpler overall.

Is either of these a good solution?  Are there better/simpler approaches that I'm missing?

Comment: "To reverse that, I could search the array for a given index number to find the corresponding coordinates" - then you have a O(length of your array) operation instead of O(1). The math is really simple and fast...

Comment: Your posted solution is fine. It's also fine to pre-generate *two* arrays to be used as lookup tables, one from index to coords, the other from coords to index. Your posted solution is more flexible if `n` hasn't been decided yet or may change in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the fast responses!  Both of those are good points, and I like the idea of 2 inversed lookup tables/arrays.

A coworker suggested he could pre-create the lookup tables and save them in nvram as well, for even faster operation.

Answer (score 0):

To keep your son out of the mental ward, do not impose the physical sequence of this particular LED arrangement on the application code generating images. There's no need to reverse the indexing of LEDs on even (or odd) numbered rows in his code. Leave that task to some final "rendering" of each "frame" performed just before the bit patterns are sent out on the wires... At that point, the 50/50 reversal operation is trivial.

The following does not define `PIXEL` or `myOutput()` as this would depend on the (unspecified) difference between mono-colour or RGB LED's in the display. The OP can adapt this to suit their needs.

```
void frameOut( const PIXEL pixels[], const size_t rows, const size_t cols ) {
    for( size_t r = 0; r < rows; r++ ) {

        PIXEL *p = pixels + r * cols; // assume this is an even row
        int incr = 1;

        if( r % 2 ) { // no, it's an odd row
            p += cols - 1; // access last pixel on this row
            incr = -1;
        }

        for( size_t c = cols; c < cols; c++ ) {
            myOutput( *p );
            p += incr;
        }
    }
}
```

An advantage to this approach is that your son could use almost any method/program to develop his graphics on a standard terminal. It's only the peculiarity of rendering bitmap/pixels on this particular LED display that needs to be solved once by an "output driver".